# In Tier 1, can you change your character’s race after being Reincarnated?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, dnd-adventurers-league, wild-magic

In Adventurers League, you can change your character’s race at will as long as he is Tier 1 (levels 1 to 4).

Can you still change your character’s race after he gets Reincarnated (possible with a certain Wild Magic Surge) ?

Answer (score 6):

## You can change your race

The rule on Character Rebuilding says

> characters in the first tier...
>   can be rebuilt after any episode or adventure. A
>   player cannot change a character’s name, but can
>   rebuild the character using the rules as presented in
>   this document. The character keeps all experience,
>   treasure, equipment, magic items, downtime, and
>   faction renown earned to that point

None of things you keep include spell effects including *reincarnate*. Furthermore, even if *reincarnate* were a story reward, it would still not be "experience, treasure, equipment, magic items, downtime, [or] faction renown."

### But, My Immersion!

If your GM is worried about the story and is treating the Character Rebuilding as a retcon (but with all events in the actual adventures still happening) to help with maintaining the roleplay, they could easily include the *reincarnate* roll in the retcon and imagine that the reincarnate is what gave the new race.

Regardless, Adventure's League is prone to plot holes by its very nature, and it is often best to just suspend disbelief in these types of situations.